# Proof for special concave form of functions

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

If $f(x)$ is a non decreasing concave function between $0$ and $1$ for $x\ge 0$, then for $a>1$ I am confident that $af(x)>f(ax)$, but I am not quite sure how to prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the proof. It actually applies to concave functions greater than zero. If there is interest I can post the proof.

Comment: Well, since you posted this as an answer, you might as well post the proof. ;)